# What is the difference between .filterMetadata(), ee.Filter.lte() and .sort() in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloud-cover

I am currently trying to obtain images that have less than 70% cloud cover (for example) and I have come across multiple variations of the same. Could you tell me what is the difference between these three approaches and which approach might be most suitable for obtaining a set of least cloudy images?

Approach 1:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 70);
```

Approach 2:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false);
```

Approach 3:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 70);
```

Answer (score 7):

Approach 1: all images in the collection within bounds that have `less than` 70%

Approach 2: keeps all the images within the bounds, but sorts them by descending order (most cloudy first)

Approach 3: all images in the collection within bounds that have `less than or equal to` 70%

However, between `filterMetadata()` (A1) and `filter(ee.Filter())` (A3) the result is the same.  The docs to `this.filterMetadata()` shows that it is equivalent to `ee.Filter()`